# Email Alerts on Cloud Function Exception

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, error-logging, google-cloud-stackdriver

I'm new to the GCP environment.

**Scenario**: I have Created a Cloud Function which triggers Based on Message Published to the Topic.

**Condition**:
Every Message Published Compulsory to have.
**Message body and 2 Attributes init.**

Cloud Function Should check whether the message and Attribute are there (Non-empty). If any of the above are empty Cloud Function must fail  ***Raise an Email Alert***.

```
**Sample Code**

import base64
import sys

def hello_pubsub(event, context):
 pubsub_message = base64.b64decode(event['data']).decode('utf-8')
 print(pubsub_message)
 pubsub_attributes = event['attributes']
 transaction_id = event['attributes']['transaction_id']
 print(transaction_id)
 refined_paths = event['attributes']['refined_paths']
 print(refined_paths)
 pubsub_timestamp = context.timestamp

 #Check whether variable are set or not.
 pubsub_message_status = bool(pubsub_message)
 transaction_id_status = bool(transaction_id)
 refined_paths_status  = bool(refined_paths)

 if(pubsub_message_status == False or transaction_id_status == False or refined_paths_status == False):
  raise RuntimeError("Message Content and Attribute are Empty")
```

***I tried this way Cloud Function is Deployed Preroroperly but NameError is Raised (Adding Photos of CF logs[image]***

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to perform the business check in your code. When you find something wrong, write a log entry.

Then, create [log based metrics](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/logs-based-metrics) on this specific log entry and an [alert on this metric](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/logs-based-metrics/charts-and-alerts#alert-on-lbm)

---

If the alerting isn't a concern, you can also add a [filter on PubSub subscription](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/filtering) (only at creation time) to only receive the valid messages (with the 2 attributes that you want, body content can't be checked)

Comment: hi @guillaume blaquiere I have written some simple logic and updated the question

Comment: @Akshay the error you receive has the `RuntimeError` misspelled - it throws `RuntimError` is not defined. You may want to review the code to see if there is a typo.

Also, this question looks different from what you initially asked, so please consider creating a separate thread for new questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Cloud Monitoring](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/support/notification-options#pubsub) to set up email alerting based on a Pub/Sub message output:

> To create a notification channel by using the Cloud Console, do the
> following:
>
> 1. In the Cloud Console, use the project picker to select your Google
>    Cloud project, and then select Monitoring, or click the following
>    button:
>
> Go to [Monitoring](https://console.cloud.google.com/monitoring?_ga=2.94969180.1579881522.1622453650-163333918.1612439028&_gac=1.117487867.1622113156.Cj0KCQjwhr2FBhDbARIsACjwLo3m8rKbOTYpk_rZ_Tqg5b_zJQEo_SE_33M6pCqIjv4Gm9hCkqx2Rj8aAjfXEALw_wcB)
>
> 2. In the Monitoring navigation pane, click notifications **Alerting**.
>
> Click **Edit notification channels**.
>
> To add a new notification channel, locate the channel type, click **Add
> new**, and then follow the channel-specific instructions contained in
> the following table:
>
> refer to the [Pub/Sub](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/support/notification-options#pubsub) table